# Log4j - need newline only sometimes

Tags: java, logging, log4j, newline, log4j2

With System.out, you have:

```
System.out.print
System.out.println
```

Occasionally I don't want a newline (like when I'm printing "About to commit transaction...done"). With System.out I would do this:

```
System.out.print("About to commit transaction...");
System.out.println("done.");
```

I can't figure out how to do this in log4j. My log4j properties file has this:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, CA
log4j.appender.CA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CA.layout.ConversionPattern=%-30c{1} %x %-30M - %m%n
```

I don't want to simply remove the "%n" and have to specify it in every single logging statement.

Is this possible in Log4j?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something creative like declaring three loggers with each a different appender (and different conversionPattern).

The first one is what you have now (the equivalent of System.println).

The 2nd one would have pattern %-30c{1} %x %-30M - %m (the equivalent of System.print)

And the 3rd one would have pattern %m%n  (the equivalent of System.println without the log message header).

This might work, but having three loggers in your code seems like not worth the hassle...

You could try requesting this as a feature in log4j2...

Comment: Thanks Remko. It's good to know that it's not supported so I don't keep wondering how to do it.

Comment: This will work well only in case of single threaded application. If you have several threads logging, you might get something like "[Thread1] About to commit transaction...[Thread2] About to commit transaction... [Thread1] done\n[Thread2] done" which will make the logs hard to read if the "no newline" appender is used often. In your example, I would advise to use DEBUG level to log start of tx (with newline), and INFO to log end of tx

Comment: Good point, yes. Any solution will suffer from this problem.  So either the questioner did not consider this or wants this for a single-threaded use case.